# using an array as a condition in an if loop

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm brand new to python and pretty new to coding in general, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to execute the for loop:

```
for numi,i in enumerate(v1):
   for numj,j in enumerate(v1):
       angle=(np.arccos(np.dot(i,j))/(np.linalg.norm(i)*np.linalg.norm(j))))*180/(np.pi)
       print(angle)
```

but I want to add a condition where the loop skips over any value or `i` or `j` that matches any element of two different arrays,

```
ala=[i for i,x in enumerate(resname) if x=='ALA']
gly=[i for i,x in enumerate(resname) if x=='GLY']
```

which contain

```
[0, 9, 14, 45, 56, 72, 87, 101, 102, 126, 145]`
```

and

```
[22, 24, 32, 39, 58, 60, 95, 97, 112, 130, 132]`
```

I tried using a conditional if statement using 'continue', but I don't know the correct syntax to get it to identify when `i` or `j`*==any element in the array*

something like

```
for numi,i in enumerate(v1):
   if i==ala or i==gly:
       continue
   else:
       for numj,j in enumerate(v1):
           if j==ala or j==gly:
               continue
           else:
               angle=(np.arccos(np.dot(i,j))/(np.linalg.norm(i)*np.linalg.norm(j))))*180/(np.pi)
               print(angle)
```

except with code that actually works

Comment: Please provide some sample input for `v1`.

Comment: Use `in`, i.e. change `if j==ala or j==gly` to `if j in ala or j in gly`...

Comment: sample of v1: `[-2.736 -0.466 -2.248]
 [-3.373 -2.93  -1.288]
 [-0.765 -3.666  1.123]
 [-1.269  1.882  1.073]
 [ 3.444  1.159 -3.183]
 [ 3.339  2.289  0.759]
 [-4.057  2.649 -0.189]
 [ 0.317  1.196 -3.699]
 [ 0.     0.     0.   ]`

Comment: doing  `if j==ala or j==gly to if j in ala or j in gly` gives me `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `any` builtin function:

Given:

```
v1 = [[-2.736, -0.466, -2.248], [-3.373, -2.93, -1.288], [-0.765, -3.666, 1.123], [-1.269, 1.882, 1.073], [3.444, 1.159, -3.183], [3.339, 2.289, 0.759], [-4.057, 2.649, -0.189], [0.317, 1.196, -3.699], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

```
for numi,i in enumerate(v1):
   if any(v in ala or v in gly for v in i):
       continue
   else:
       for numj,j in enumerate(v1):
           if any(v in ala or v in gly for v in j)::
               continue
           else:
               angle=(np.arccos(np.dot(i,j))/(np.linalg.norm(i)*np.linalg.norm(j))))*180/(np.pi)
               print(angle)
```

Comment: I get "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" when using this method

Comment: I actually get this error with every method you've listed

Comment: @help231_ I am updating my answer. You didn't make it clear that `v1` is an array of arrays

Comment: oops. didn't realize that necessarily mattered. v1 is an array of coordinates, and i'm trying to find the angle between each coordinate and all the other coordinates within the array, while filtering out specific coordinates that give me invalid answers.

Comment: OH MY GOD THAT WORKED! I just used `any`, not `not any`. I swear I tried to use the any() function several times and couldn't get it to run properly. I guess my formatting was the issue. Thank you so much!!